# Although sometimes it works, I get ".filter is not a function" in my React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

```
  28 | <Grid.Row>
  29 |   {cars.map((car) => (
  30 |     <Grid.Column style={{marginBottom:"1em"}}>
> 31 |       <CarComponent car={car} imagePath={carImages.filter(image=>image.car.id===car.id)[0].imagePath}></CarComponent>
     | ^  32 |       
  33 |     </Grid.Column>
  34 |   ))}
```

I get the information (brand, color, description etc.) and photos of the vehicles from separate services (carController, carImageController). As such, when trying to list the cars, I choose the photo with the carId equal to the id of that car in the list of photos for each car in the car list. I write the imagePath as carImages.filter(image=>image.car.id===car.id)[0].imagePath} to do this check on the data coming from my photo service and send it as props to the car component. Sometimes I get this typeError when everything is working fine. Why might it be caused?

**Car Function Component:**

```
 export default function CarComponent({ car, imagePath}) {
return (
<div>
  <Card style={{height:"388px"}}>
    <Image 
      src={imagePath}
      wrapped
      ui="false"
      style={{height:"200px"}}
      
    />
    <Card.Content>
      <Card.Header>{car.brand.name}</Card.Header>
      <Card.Meta>
        <span className="date">{car.modelYear}</span>
      </Card.Meta>
      <Card.Description>{car.description}</Card.Description>
    </Card.Content>
    <Card.Content extra style={{color:"black"}} >
      <h3 >{car.dailyPrice} ₺</h3>

      <Button secondary animated>
        <Button.Content visible>Kirala</Button.Content>
        <Button.Content hidden>
          <Icon name="arrow right" />
        </Button.Content>
      </Button>
    </Card.Content>
  </Card>
</div>
);}
```

**Car Image Class**

```
export default class CarImageService{
getCarImages(){
    return axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/images/getAll")
}
}
```

**CarsList Page**

```
export default function CarsList() {


const [cars, setCars] = useState([]);

  const [carImages, setCarImage] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    let carImageService = new CarImageService();
    carImageService
      .getCarImages()
      .then((result) => setCarImage(result.data.data));
      
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    let carService = new CarService();
    carService.getCars().then((result) => setCars(result.data.data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Grid columns={3} >
        <Grid.Row>
          {cars.map((car) => (
            <Grid.Column style={{marginBottom:"1em"}}>
              <CarComponent car={car} imagePath={carImages.filter(image=>image.car.id===car.id)[0].imagePath}></CarComponent>
              
            </Grid.Column>
          ))}
        </Grid.Row>
       
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Get All Car Images Request URL:** http://localhost:8080/api/images/getAll

**Get All Car Images Response Body:**

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": null,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 26,
      "imagePath": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dp39jsge0/image/upload/v1629406293/hx80jyfrus88tar0psq4.png",
      "createdAt": "2021-08-19",
      "car": {
        "id": 1,
        "modelYear": 2017,
        "dailyPrice": 600,
        "description": "A6 2.0TDI QUATTRO EDITION",
        "brand": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Audi"
        },
        "color": {
          "id": 8,
          "name": "Beyaz"
        },
        "busy": false
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 27,
      "imagePath": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dp39jsge0/image/upload/v1629406541/dynoc7dnjcbns0mv2y1m.png",
      "createdAt": "2021-08-19",
      "car": {
        "id": 2,
        "modelYear": 2018,
        "dailyPrice": 400,
        "description": "ALFA ROMEO GIULIETTA 1.6 JTD PROGRESSİON 120 HP",
        "brand": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Alfa Romeo"
        },
        "color": {
          "id": 9,
          "name": "Gri"
        },
        "busy": false
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 28,
      "imagePath": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dp39jsge0/image/upload/v1629406744/fmvdbmqaennil4ptdyoc.png",
      "createdAt": "2021-08-19",
      "car": {
        "id": 3,
        "modelYear": 2018,
        "dailyPrice": 550,
        "description": "BMW 320 DİZEL OTOMATİK-EDITION M SPORT",
        "brand": {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "BMW"
        },
        "color": {
          "id": 10,
          "name": "Kırmızı"
        },
        "busy": false
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 29,
      "imagePath": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dp39jsge0/image/upload/v1629406930/dq4htj3rrdjlbpiqa8iq.png",
      "createdAt": "2021-08-20",
      "car": {
        "id": 4,
        "modelYear": 2016,
        "dailyPrice": 700,
        "description": "C180 COUPE",
        "brand": {
          "id": 10,
          "name": "Mercedes - Benz"
        },
        "color": {
          "id": 11,
          "name": "Lacivert"
        },
        "busy": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Refresh page a few times:[sample of list of cars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAeD0.png)**

Comment: Because some cars do not have photos, so `carImages` is `null` and you can't filter on null?

Comment: Change `const [carImages, setCarImage] = useState({});` to `const [carImages, setCarImage] = useState([]);`

Comment: Thanks you all. It works fine for the moment. I had forgot to change back the initial state from object to array.

Comment: Guys, I guess there is a problem with imagePath this time. "Cannot read property 'imagePath' of undefined" error occurs. Am I use .filter() method correctly? I tried to create CarComponent by using: <CarComponent car={car} imagePath={carImages.filter(image=>image.car.id===car.id)[0].imagePath}></CarComponent>. there is a [0] there because only by this way I reach the pure path string. The zeroth index of carImages.filter(image=>image.car.id===car.id) is an actual carImage object. (@Dominik you may move this an answer of this question if it should be)

Answer (score 1):

The initial value for `carImages` must be array, not object.

`const [carImages, setCarImage] = useState([]);`

Notice the initial value: `[]`, not `{}`

For the second error:

You need to check the result of `filter` because `filter` returns an empty array when `getCars()` returns before `getCarImages()` or if some cars don't have any images. Plus, to get rid of the array, you need to use `find` instead of `filter` because you expect a single result.

```
export default function CarsList() {


const [cars, setCars] = useState([]);

  const [carImages, setCarImage] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let carImageService = new CarImageService();
    carImageService
      .getCarImages()
      .then((result) => setCarImage(result.data.data));
      
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    let carService = new CarService();
    carService.getCars().then((result) => setCars(result.data.data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Grid columns={3} >
        <Grid.Row>
          {cars.map((car) => {
            let image = carImages.find(i=>i.car.id===car.id);
            return 
            <Grid.Column style={{marginBottom:"1em"}}>
              <CarComponent car={car} imagePath={image === undefined ? undefined :image.imagePath}></CarComponent>
              
            </Grid.Column>
          })}
        </Grid.Row>
       
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```